# 'Series2' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I'm must be missing something really obvious here.  This code couldn't be much more simple and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Kent
{
    public class Series2<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        static void Test()
        {
            Series2<char> s2 = new Series2<char>();
            s2.GetEnumerator();                       //*** compile error here
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return null;
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

At the line indicated, I'm getting this error:

'Series2<char>' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator()'...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [explicitly implemented the interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx) and therefore can only access them via an instance of the interface (or a cast):

```
        IEnumerable<char> s2 = new Series2<char>();
        s2.GetEnumerator();
```

or

```
        IEnumerable s2 = new Series2<char>();
        s2.GetEnumerator();
```

or

```
        Series2<char> s2 = new Series2<char>();
        ((IEnumerable<char>)s2).GetEnumerator();
```

will all work.